# Maintaining consistent look across multiple views in Razor and HTML?

Tags: html, angularjs, razor

I have ASP.Net MVC 5 application with `Layout.cshtml` and I have included the HTML view page. But I want to keep the consistent look and feel across multiple views in my application. I know I can do this if I have a Razor view page:

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
```

If I'm also using the same above code on the HTML View page, it doesn't pick up the Layout as it does in Razor page.

Comment: "on my HTML page it doesn't seem to work out" > Please explain that. It is totally unclear what you mean with that.

Comment: You mean, as a regular HTML file?

Comment: Yes , but what i want is for my HTML page to have what the Layout.cshtml have e.g Navbar header and footer .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In html page you can't call '_Layout.cshtml' file directly to use layout , you have to add style and html tags manually in new created html file which you have in '_Layout.cshtml'. There is an option to call '_Layout.cshtml' using iframe but it is useful only if you don't want to apply server side logic, which is of less possibility.

Comment: Welcome @TheDreamer , enjoy development... :)